pip install snowflake-connector-python fails building wheels
building 'snowflake.connector.nanoarrow_arrow_iterator' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for snowflake-connector-python
Failed to build snowflake-connector-python
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (snowflake-connector-python)
I tried pip install snowflake-connector-python also pip install pyarrow
python --version
Python 3.13.0
pip --version
pip 24.3.1

For installation issues with Python modules it is often best to look at GitHub or PyPi. When I search for "snowflake-connector-python issues 3.13 github" this link enlightens me to a possible cause of your issue https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/2087 - follow the page for updates

There are no wheels for snowflake connector for python 3.13 yet
https://pypi.org/project/snowflake-connector-python/#files
Latest available version is for python 3.12.4

will update when cp313 wheel file will be available

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/2087#issuecomment-2440544911

You can wok with python 3.12 until python 3.13 is fully supported.
